# Getting "Deprecated: ini_set()" on a fresh Homestead vagrant VM

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant

I'm getting this 'weird' error on a [homestead](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead) vm

> Deprecated: ini_set(): Use of mbstring.http_output is deprecated

I did some research but couldn't find anything helpful
here's some info about my enviroment

php -v 5.6.0

And here's the complete error, just in case

[image]

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: how to fix the above mentioned error. it's a brand new instance of homestead, there should be no errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mbstring.http_output` was deprecated as of PHP 5.6. PHP 5.6 and later users should leave this empty and set [`default_charset`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.default-charset) instead. (See http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.configuration.php).

Comment: thanks, that was exactly the problem. I guess I should consider doing a downgrade for PHP or upgrade my laravel enviroment. Owe you one mate!

Comment: @feresr Usually upgrading would be preferred if possible, especially if you are using a really old version of laravel.

Comment: [Deprecated Features  in 5.6](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.deprecated.php).

Answer (score 7):

Incase someone else stumbles across this, I resolved this with the following:

To note, the app I'm trying to run on php 5.6.14 is built using Laravel 4.0.

I added the following to my composer.json's required:

```
"patchwork/utf8": "~1.1"
```

Then I ran 'composer update patchwork/utf8'

I also had to update the app/config/session.php cookie variable to something other than laravel_session as the newer site was causing a session error.. So - I basically changed 'cookie'=>'laravel_session' to 'cookie'=>'laravel_session_4'.

composer dump-autoload and the world was spinning correctly again.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

For UTF-8 settings I use this

```
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.6.0') < 0) {
    ini_set('mbstring.internal_encoding', 'UTF-8');
    ini_set('mbstring.http_input', 'auto');
    ini_set('mbstring.http_output', 'UTF-8');
}
ini_set('mbstring.language', 'Neutral');
ini_set('mbstring.encoding_translation', 'On');
ini_set('mbstring.detect_order', 'auto');
ini_set('mbstring.substitute_character', 'none');
ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');
```